# Proposed a long time ago

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual, rebus

What do we have here?

---

[image]

Last letter in order: r, h, e, r

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what we have here is

> The Four Classical Elements - Air, Earth, Fire and Water

Reasoning

> The number of sides of the shape surrounding each image corresponds to the number of letters in the associated element.
>  The images themselves can join with the element to form a word or phrase as follows:
>  Plane, corresponding to **Air**plane.
>  Mother, corresponding to Mother **Earth**.
>  Bon, corresponding to Bon**fire** (the image is the symbol for Bon Jovi and the tick and cross represent that we want the "Bon" part rather than the "Jovi" part, thanks to the OP for explaining).
>  Fall, corresponding to **Water**fall.
>  The last letters given in order confirm the answer.

Comment: Well done! Your overall answer is correct but for the third image my intention was rot13 (Obasver. Gur vzntr vf n ybtb bs
Oba Wbiv jurer "Wbiv" vf znexrq erq jvgu n pebff juvyr "Oba" vf terra jvgu n purpx znex, zrnavat "Oba" vf gur jbeq V'z ybbxvat sbe (rkpyhqr "Wbiv"))

Comment: @Prim3numbah Ah, that makes so much sense, thank you